# Link react-hook-form Controller to a state value

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

I'm trying to link react-hook-form Controller to a state value, but it is not rendering the value.

```
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

...

// here is my fields values
const [ addBill, setAddBill ] = useState({
    debitAmt: '',
    invoiceNumber: '',
    memo: '',
    invoiceDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
});

// here is how I'm rendering the Controller Input
<FormGroup className="mr-10 mb-10">
    <Label for="debitAmt" className="mr-sm-10">Debit Amt</Label>
    <Controller
        render={ ({value}) => {
            return (
            <NumberFormat
                value={value}
                thousandSeparator={true}
                prefix={"$"}
                onValueChange={(v) => {
                    setAddBill({...addBill, debitAmt: v.floatValue === undefined ? '' : v.floatValue})
                }}
            /> );
        }}
        name="debitAmt"
        id="debitAmt"
        variant="outlined"
        defaultValue={addBill.debitAmt}
        value={addBill.debitAmt}
        getInputRef={register({ required: true })} aria-invalid={errors.debitAmt ? "true" : "false"}
        control={control}
        className="form-control"
        style={setErrorStyle(errors.debitAmt)}
    />
    {errors.debitAmt && (
        <span style={{ color: "red" }} role="alert">required</span>
    )}
</FormGroup>
```

Then, when I call:

```
setAddBill({
   ...addBill, 
   debitAmt: 10
});
```

It does not update the value for the NumberFormat. How can I connect the Controller to the state variable?

Comment: where do you have useForm?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I've managed to do it by passing onChange to render alongside value: render={ ({ value, onChange }) => ... }

Comment: If you still need help put a sandbox, I'll try to help you

Answer (score -1):

As you can see on [Controller documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller), Controller's render method procue value and onChange properties. You should use like this:

```
<Controller
    render={ ({value, onChange}) => {
        return (
        <NumberFormat
            value={value}
            thousandSeparator={true}
            prefix={"$"}
            onValueChange={(v) => {
                setAddBill({...addBill, debitAmt: v.floatValue === undefined ? '' : v.floatValue});
                onChange(v);
            }}
        /> );
    }}
    name="debitAmt"
    id="debitAmt"
    variant="outlined"
    defaultValue={addBill.debitAmt}
    value={addBill.debitAmt}
    getInputRef={register({ required: true })} aria-invalid={errors.debitAmt ? "true" : "false"}
    control={control}
    className="form-control"
    style={setErrorStyle(errors.debitAmt)}
/>
```

In React-hook-form, by default, you dont need to control your input states. If you let RHF save it, you can retreive the state using [Watch API](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch) or by submiting a form using [handleSubmit](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/handlesubmit).

Comment: I think you just added onChange in addition to my code. It did not solve the issue

Comment: You forgot to read the last part of the answer. To work, you should let RHF manage states. To retreive data, use the handleSubmit. Maybe a codesandbox could be helpfull.